# Length-Converter in React JS | React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Create a length converter app which converts the input length to the required length based on the conversion rates.
Use the following conversion rates
KM{
M:1000
YARD:1093
}
M{
KM:0.001
YARD:1.09
}
YARD:{
M:0.91
KM:0.0009
}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBC7a.png)

- For example picker 1 has KM as selected an picker2 has M as selected option, if the picker1 is changed to same value as of picker2 that is M picker2 will take the value of picker 1 that is KM

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - show some code / show us what you already did

Comment: Can you please provide some code/data to rely on ?